# Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04, monitor says mode unsupported/out of range

Tags: 14.04, display, monitor, system

Monitor says mode unsupported/out of range during installation of ubuntu 14.04 and never boots to the ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We will need more information in order to help you with this problem. (Example would be: what type of computer/monitor)

Answer (score 2):

During installation as soon as the computer starts to boot continually tap any key until you see this screen, [image: parameters] then choose nomodeset, the Ubuntu install cd should now boot to the desktop.

After you install Ubuntu follow the directions below to set the resolution permanently on your installed Ubuntu desktop.

If you do not press any keys when the computer is booting up it should load Ubuntu, this is if Ubuntu is already installed, but this may take a couple of minutes, then you can do the following.

If it is only happening in GRUB and you can boot into Ubuntu then please do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change this line:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Then save and exit the document.

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If after you install Ubuntu it will not boot to the desktop Hold down (right) SHIFT to display the menu during boot. In certain cases, pressing the ESC key may also display the menu you will get this screen [image: boot menu] then press the `e` key and go down to the line that starts with `linux /bootvmlinuz` after the words quite splash add nomodeset, then press F10 to boot. [image]

After you boot if you had out of range issue's still follow the directions above for making the changes permanent in an installed Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: This happens during installation, how do I fix that?

Comment: I am working on the instructions now.