# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 - Out of Range issue (in Skylake)

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Studio in a brand new machine. It has UEFI and Grub2.

Problem is that after a Ubuntu (Studio) splash screen I get a "signal out of range" error. And all I can do is press ctrl+alt+F1 to log in without X.

--

So, I read things like disabling **UEFI** and **Fast Boot** and so I did. That just changed the look and feel of the *grub2* menu. But the *Out of Range* issue remains.

--

Then, some people talks about using *nomodeset*. But I just can't find where to put that.

--

Other people says "edit /etc/default/grub and uncomment the GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 line". So I did. The I'm supposed to run: 
sudo update-grub2

Well, that last line won't work. I'm getting this error:
**failed to get canonical path of /cow**

I understand this has something to do with mounting something. Not sure if my new SSD disk (that I didn't format at all, is brand new). Any clue?

--

Also some people talks about using *grub-repair* but that seems to work only for people already having a running X environment. And I don't. If I burn a recovery CD all I get is the grub screen.

--

Finally, there're the ones who talks about compatibility issues with *skylake*, and mention adding this param somewhere: i915.preliminary_hw_support=1

And I just don't know what are they talking about.

--

More that all I'd like to understand where is supposed grub to live? In my pendrive? Or is it part of the kernel now? I just don't get it.

Thanks in advance.

--

My hard:
. ASUS z170-A mother
. nvidia gtx 960
. samsung ssd

Answer (score 0):

News: I was able to run from the live-pendrive and install by using the nomodeset param. I learned how here:
[Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04, monitor says mode unsupported/out of range](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484132/trying-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-monitor-says-mode-unsupported-out-of-range)

Bsically, pressing the "e" key in the grub menu and adding that string after the words "quiet splash".